# Is there a simpler way to find a 3x3 matrix in a 11x11 matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

A few friends and I are creating a simulation based game using java where our "players" go out on an 11x11 matrix full of a Class called Chunk. In order for the players to be able to interact with the world around it, it requires us to see the information of the Chunks in a 3x3 surrounding the player.

**Example(smaller matrix size, x=Nothing There, o=Person):**

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxoxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

We would need to be able to collect the chunks surrounding the player(o)(in this case row's [1],[2],[3] and col's[4],[5],[6]). Of course, the 3x3 matrix cannot leave the bounds of the matrix and if it does we just ignore the ones that aren't there and collect the Chunks we can collect. Currently, we have a block of code that works for the desired task but we feel like it could be made faster, cleaner, or completely remade in another way.

**fullMap** is an array which is initialized to be an 11x11 full of Chunk's and
**currentRow**, **currentCol** both are integers which relate to the position in fullMap the player is currently in.

```
for(int row = 0; row < fullMap.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < fullMap[row].length; col++) {
            if (((row == currentRow-1) && (col == currentCol)) && currentRow != 0) {
                //store the chunk
            } else if (((row == currentRow-1) && (col == currentCol+1)) && (currentRow != 0 && currentCol != 10)) {
                //store the chunk
            } else if (((row == currentRow-1) && (col == currentCol-1)) && (currentRow != 0 && currentCol != 0)) {
                //store the chunk
            } else if (((row == currentRow) && (col == currentCol+1)) && currentCol != 10) {
                //store the chunk
            } else if (((row == currentRow) && (col == currentCol-1))  && currentCol != 0) {
                //store the chunk
            } else if (((row == currentRow+1) && (col == currentCol+1)) && (currentRow != 10 && currentCol != 10)){
                //store the chunk
            } else if (((row == currentRow+1) && (col == currentCol)) && currentRow != 10) {
                //store the chunk
            } else if (((row == currentRow+1) && (col == currentCol-1)) && (currentRow != 10 && currentCol != 0)){
                //store the chunk
            }
    }
}
```

If other information is needed I am happy to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over the `fullMap`, do you?
You know the (`currentRow`, `currentCol`) and from there you go -1/+1 in each direction. In total you will have 9 fields to check.

```
    ...
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
      for (int j = -1; j <= 1 ; j++) {
        if (isMovePossible(currentRow + i, currentCol + j)) {
          // store chunk
        }
      }
    }
    ...


  private static boolean isMovePossible(int row, int col) {
    return row >= 0 && row <= 10 && col >= 0 && col <=10;
  }
```

Comment: I thought about that but I felt it was an easy solution to the problem I had. Now that I see this answer I really don't know the purpose of iterating through the entire map except to waste time. Thank you a lot this seems to work and simplifies the process a lot! I'm trying to use this project to learn better coding practices rather than doing the thing that pops up in my head first, but yeah thanks again.